# Cocoa NSTabView coding style question

Tags: cocoa, macos, coding-style, nstabview

I have a coding style question which probably should be asked of a senior mac programmer at work - but since I'm the only mac programmer, well, SO it is.  I have a pop-up GUI for my software (3D models, data visualization) and the pop-up is Mainly a Tabbed control with a ton of stuff in each tab (sliders, radio buttons, checkboxes, etc.)  With something like 20 controls per tab, and maybe half a dozen tabs... using a single controller for all the views is going to get unwieldly very quickly.

Is having a MainViewController which loads a bunch of Tabs good style?

```
NSView *tabA = [[NSView alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabA.nib" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/BOB.app"]];
NSView *tabB = [[NSView alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabB.nib" bundle:[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/BOB.app"]];
```

It's kindof how I do it on iOS, but I'm not sure for Mac OS X.  I prefer a style that offers maintainability and flexibility, as the code is going through prototyping and I may need to change it frequently.

If it's not good style, what is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yours is a reasonable style. You create an `NSViewController` subclass for each tab, and assign it to the `NSTabView` using `NSTabViewItem`.

By the way, I think it's better to have

```
NSViewController *tabAcontroller = [[TabAController alloc] init];
```

with `@interface TabAController:NSViewController ... @end` with `init` defined as

```
-init{
    self=[super initWithNibName:@"tabA" bundle:nil];
    if(self){
        ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note that you don't need the extension `.nib` when you call `initWithNibName:bundle:`. And you **should not** specify the hard-coded path of the app. In iOS, the app's position is a given by the OS (with cryptic folder names,) but on OS X a user can freely move the app bundle to anywhere he wants. So, never refer to the main bundle as `[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"hard coded path"]`. Use just `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, or just `nil` in most cases. It's written in the documentation when you can just use `nil`.

Comment: GREAT.  It's little things like suggesting subclassing (which helps encapsulation) that I'd never find anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Each tab tends to be different, and it often needs specialized support codes, so I think it's better to put these codes in the specialized View Controllers. Then the controller of the tab view can just swap individual views.